# How are docker credentials saved in podman?

Tags: docker-registry, podman

In docker whenever we login to a registry their credentials get saved in the config.json file right?

How is this done in podman? where are the credentials saved when I have podman installed and i do docker login into a registry? If i have podman installed, will the .docker/config.json not get created?

Can I know how this config.json functionality is handled in podman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [podman-login man page](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-login.1.html) the credentials are stored in $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/containers/auth.json (assuming Linux). For example, mine is stored in /run/user/1000/containers/auth.json. It will use .docker/config.json if it exists, but it will not create it.

If you want to change this behavior, you can specify the --authfile switch or set the REGISTRY_AUTH_FILE environment variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me find the auth.json file which I could find previously and was confused!! And by changing the behavior do you mean making podman use config.json instead of auth.json?

Comment: Also do credentials get saved to auth.json when we do "docker login" or do we need to specifically execute "podman login" command for the credentials to get saved in the auth.json file?

Comment: Yes, you can use the --authfile argument or REGISTRY_AUTH_FILE environment variable to change the path (although I have only used --authfile). For example, "podman login --authfile=$HOME/.docker/config.json docker.io". But keep in mind that with either of thos options, you do need to use them for your subsequent commands.